# ASP.Net minimal API

Tags: c#, asp.net-minimal-apis, carter

I am searching for a solution to group my Modules with Charter. I want to set a base namespace and Version Set per group and set multiple groups. Something like this:

```
var apiA = app.MapGroup("api/a/").WithApiVersionSet(ApiVersioning.VersionSetA);
apiA.MapCarter();

var apiA = app.MapGroup("api/b/").WithApiVersionSet(ApiVersioning.VersionSetB);
apiB.MapCarter();
```

Any ideas how i could this getting to work?

Thanks